# RVM Denied Permission Error across the board - OS X Mavericks - Ruby 2.0.0?

Tags: ruby, rvm, permission-denied

I have reached a standstill after combing through tons of fixes. I'm new to Ruby/programming and had a perfectly fine, working (single user) install of Ruby/RVM earlier today, however something changed and I have probably done more damage than good trying to fix it.

Essentially, when I try to run my basic .rb file, its gives me:

```
 ruby: No such file or directory -- doom.rb (LoadError)
```

I attempted uninstalling RVM and reinstalling, I think that's where I screwed things up. I used `rvm implode` and I think it was an incomplete removal. Now when I try it, it simply says `command not found`. That same message shows up for most other fixes, `repair` and `get head`, what have you.

If I try to reinstall over whatever is/isn't left, I get a screen full of Permission Denial Errors and already-existing objects:

```
rm: /Users/caroljones/.rvm/src/rvm/patchsets/ruby/1.9.3/p385: Permission denied
.
.
.
scripts/wrapper: Can't unlink already-existing object
scripts/zsh/: Can't update time for scripts/zsh
scripts/zsh/Completion/: Can't update time for scripts/zsh/Completion
scripts/zsh/Completion/_rvm: Can't unlink already-existing object
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Could not extract RVM sources.
```

If I run `echo $PATH`, I get this:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/
```

Ruby is installed fine:

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

I think it comes down to not doing a clean uninstall, but I cannot figure out how to pinpoint what garbage is left over from imploding.

Let me know if I can give you any other info to clear up my question.

EDIT: If I run `which ruby` I get this output:

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

And for `$ ls -al ~ | grep rvm` I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x    5 caroljones  staff    170 May  5 17:35 .rvm
```

Comment: We don't have any view into your home directory, or how RVM/Ruby are currently "sitting", so we need additional information. Append the output of `which ruby` and `ls -al ~ | grep rvm` to you question. That will give us a little with which we can start working.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you used `sudo` at some point in your (un)installation process, which changed your permissions, and would explain your permission denial errors.

Your path isn't configured right; "local/bin" directories should be before things like "usr/bin" directories. The idea of a "local" directory is it houses commands you installed, plus commands that are overrides/updates to pre-existing ones that were installed by the system. When the "local" directories are before "usr" ones in the PATH, their commands will be found, and used, before the "usr" ones. As is, your path fails to allow that. Instead of:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/
```

It should look like:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

That won't get Ruby or RVM running correctly, but it will help your command-line experience work the way it's supposed to.

Once we have more information about your environment/configuration, we can provide solutions to get your system working correctly.

---

> there was a 'sudo' fix I used at some point in the process that screwed with my permissions, as you suggested.

`sudo` will cause files and directories that were created as the command ran, to be owned by root, and attempts to change those will give you the errors you see. You can fix that problem by returning the ownership of the files and directories back to you. Note however, you do *NOT* want to do this willy-nilly. Changing ownership can turn your machine into a brick if you do it to the wrong files.

To change the ownership of ~/.rvm and all its contents, use:

```
sudo chown -R caroljones ~/.rvm
```

Following that, the permission problems for accessing files in ~/.rvm should be fixed.

At that point you can run:

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

to completely remove RVM, similar to what `rvm implode` would do. At that point I think you'd be able to reinstall RVM safely.

Before doing that, read [the RVM installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) completely and carefully. There are instructions for how your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile should be modified to allow RVM to be initialized when a shell is created. People gloss over that process, thinking RVM has done everything fine, but don't understand what it does to tie into their system. That's not a good idea, because knowing what is supposed to be in place will make it easy to diagnose and fix problems.

One of your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile files should have the code that loads RVM when the shell is created. That should be at the bottom of the file; It doesn't have to be last, but you do need to understand how and why it can be moved.

Comment: Now that you mention it, there was a 'sudo' fix I used at some point in the process that screwed with my permissions, as you suggested. What code should I run to get you environment/config stats that would help?

Comment: I'm using Mavericks 10.9.2 along with Sublime Text 2 and iTerm. I have rails-4.1.0, Xcode 5, and Homebrew.

Comment: I added some additional information about how to clean up the directory.

Comment: Alright, I applied the 2 fixes you recommended and restarted my session. When I ran both `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`, I did still end up getting a permission denied return: `bash: /Users/caroljones/.bash_profile: Permission denied`

Comment: You don't need to "run" .bashrc or .bash_profile. They're automatically run when you start a shell session. Rerunning them can make your path funky. The error message you receive *should* tell you what command caused the permission denied. Knowing that is important.

Comment: I'm a bit lost on what/where the error message I'm looking for should be. When I run `echo $PATH` now, I get this back: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/:/Users/caroljones/.rvm/bin`. I did successfully get a clean reinstall of RVM running, but am still getting an error when I try to run my .rb file: `ruby: No such file or directory -- doom.rb (LoadError)`

Comment: There is a bug in oh-my-zsh that seems to be causing some issues with PATH. I don't know if this is possibly linked to my issue?https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1351#issuecomment-10939525